# Is it possible to undelete task from greenhopper /Jira?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I deleted few tasks by mistake is it possible to un-delete them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard luck. In Jira, delete really does mean delete. Issue data gets removed from the database completely

Follow below links to find any workaround:

- https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/57259/how-to-restore-deleted-issue-in-jira
- http://osdir.com/ml/java.jira.user/2008-01/msg00102.html

Comment: You can change who has the Delete permission to reduce the risk of this